# Erro ao ler XML com JAXB: todos itens nulos após Unmarshal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Tenho um arquivo XML simples de estoque com o seguinte formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<estoque>
    <item Nome="Impressora XL2N" Peso="13 kg" Armazem="8" Quantidade="12" Preco="R$ 8505,00" />
    <item Nome="Scanner N-13 " Peso="5 kg" Armazem="5" Quantidade="8" Preco="R$ 1505,00" />
    <item Nome="Monitor PH-1" Peso="2 kg" Armazem="1" Quantidade="45" Preco="R$ 123,99" />
</estoque>
```

Criei as classes de modelo do XML anotadas para serem lidas usando JAXB. Ficaram assim:

Raiz.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="estoque")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Raiz {

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private Item[] itens;

    public Item[] getItens() {
        return itens;
    }
}
```

E a Item.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Nome;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Peso;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Armazem;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Quantidade;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Preco;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [Nome=" + Nome + ", Peso=" + Peso + ", Armazem=" + Armazem
                + ", Quantidade=" + Quantidade + ", Preco=" + Preco + "]";
    }

}
```

Mas ao chamar o método de Unmarshal do JAXB, o retorno não é o esperado. Ele até percebe a quantidade de itens (3), mas eles estão todos nulos:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Raiz.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

File xml = new File("/home/worknz/estoque.xml");

Raiz raiz = (Raiz) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

System.out.println(raiz.getItens().length);
for(Item i: raiz.getItens()) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Saída:

```
3
Item [Nome=null, Peso=null, Armazem=null, Quantidade=null, Preco=null]
Item [Nome=null, Peso=null, Armazem=null, Quantidade=null, Preco=null]
Item [Nome=null, Peso=null, Armazem=null, Quantidade=null, Preco=null]
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

O erro é bem simples, mas difícil de ser detectado. O XML está com os atributos em maiúsculas (Nome, Peso, Armazem, etc).

Na classe Java, mesmo colocando as variáveis com nomes em maiúsculas não é suficiente. Há duas opções:

**1. Anotar explicitamente com a propriedade "name" do XMLAttribute:**

> ```
> @XmlAttribute(name="Nome")
> private String Nome;
>
> @XmlAttribute(name="Peso")
> private String Peso;
>
> @XmlAttribute(name="Armazem")
> private String Armazem;
>
> @XmlAttribute(name="Quantidade")
> private String Quantidade;
>
> @XmlAttribute(name="Preco")
> private String Preco;
> ```

**2. Trocar os atributos do XML para minúsculas, e também no Java:**

> ```
> @XmlAttribute
> private String nome;
>
> @XmlAttribute
> private String peso;
>
> @XmlAttribute
> private String armazem;
>
> @XmlAttribute
> private String quantidade;
>
> @XmlAttribute
> private String preco;
> ```

e

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <estoque>
>     <item nome="Impressora XL2N" peso="13 kg" armazem="8" quantidade="12" preco="R$ 8505,00" />
>     <item nome="Scanner N-13 " peso="5 kg" armazem="5" quantidade="8" preco="R$ 1505,00" />
>     <item nome="Monitor PH-1" peso="2 kg" armazem="1" quantidade="45" preco="R$ 123,99" />
> </estoque>
> ```

**Nos dois casos, a saída será a mesma:**

```
3
Item [Nome=Impressora XL2N, Peso=13 kg, Armazem=8, Quantidade=12, Preco=R$ 8505,00]
Item [Nome=Scanner N-13 , Peso=5 kg, Armazem=5, Quantidade=8, Preco=R$ 1505,00]
Item [Nome=Monitor PH-1, Peso=2 kg, Armazem=1, Quantidade=45, Preco=R$ 123,99]
```